# Passing variables to views in Laravel4

Tags: php, layout, view, controller, laravel

I am very newbie about all of these PHP Frameworks. I was once created my own framework by using phpbb's template functions, language support and sessions. I turned them into a Model-View framework. I decided that is too complicated and searched for a new framework.

Right now I am using laravel and its quite well yet I still couldn't figure how to handle controllers and views. Here comes my stuck part.

I was using my phpbb's framework by creating a file.php to root folder and create a .html file styles folder. phpbb's framework can render a html file by calling

```
$template->set_filenames(array(
'body' => 'file.html'
));
```

however i can pass every variable to file.html from the controller.php like this :

```
$template->assign_var('THREAD_ID', $row['id']);
$template->assign_var('THREAD_NAME', $row['title']);

even cycles were too easy

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
    $template->assign_block_vars('post_row', array
    (
        'ID'    =>  $row['post_id'],
        'COUNT' => $count++,
        'USERNAME' => $row['post_username'],
        'DATE' => $row['post_datetime'],
        'ENTRY' => $row['post_entry'],
    )
    );
}

 and then for rendering the view

 $template->set_filenames(array(
 'body' => 'file.html'
 ));
```

this is what i couldnt understand in laravel.
I am using this but when I using this for another variable it gives me error.

```
$this->layout->nest('content', 'index', array(
  'data' => 'pokeçu'
));
```

in documents they made examples just for one variable. I dont know how to continue my way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Laravel 3, as that is the current stable version. There's [a section in the Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/views#binding-data-to-views) covering this. Basically you're going to be using the View class in whatever way suits your app best. Remember, your controller methods (or route closures) will always *return* something, usually a View instance. To bind data to that view, the simplest method is to use with($data[, $value]) where $data is either an associative key-value array, or $data is a key and $value is the value.  For example:

```
public function get_index()
{
    $thread = array('id'=>23, 'name'=>'Skidoo');
    return View::make('home.index')->with($thread);
}
```

Note the return. You don't need to return it right away. You can also instantiate the View object, and bind data to it directly:

```
public function get_index()
{
    $view = View::make('home.index');
    $view->thread = array('id'=>23, 'name'=>'Skidoo');
    $view->welcome = 'Welcome to My Site!';
    return $view;
}
```

In addition to the docs, there are a couple of recent tutorial books available. Check out the Learn section on the Laravel website at http://laravel.com/

Comment: oh you mean $view->whatever is gonna be a variable? like {{$whatever}} ?

Comment: Yeah, if you're using Blade views that's exactly how it would look. If you're using vanilla php views, it would be <?=$whatever?>.